# What is the right way to change the display name in an Android FileProvider?

Tags: android, android-sharing, android-fileprovider

Say if I have filename *1234567.png* on the internal filesystem - say I want to send it to the user with a share `intent` as *CoolPicture.png* - ie subclass fileprovider and replace the query method.

Is using a matrix cursor based on the cursor from super a good plan?

It seems like `DISPLAY_NAME` and `SIZE` are the only columns but doesn't seem to confirm if `SIZE` is int or string.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

I'll plan to post my code after I answer it, I just wanted to get an idea of best practice, and perhaps contribute.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is using a matrix cursor based on the cursor from super a good plan?

You could do that, and it's probably OK. After all, `FileProvider` itself uses a `MatrixCursor`.

To modify an existing `Cursor`, I use `CursorWrapper` myself, in [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/provider/src/com/commonsware/cwac/provider/LegacyCompatCursorWrapper.java), then in `query()` wrap the `Cursor` I get from the base `ContentProvider` implementation (e.g., `FileProvider`) in my wrapper.

> It seems like DISPLAY_NAME and SIZE re the only columns but doesn't seem to confirm if SIZE is int or string.

That's one of the reasons I went with the `CursorWrapper`, to avoid messing with any existing values.

That being said, [the existing `FileProvider` implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java) uses a `Long` (`file.length()`, auto-boxed).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the new [androidx.core.content.FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) has now a second [`getUriForFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) method with an additional `displayName` param which sets the value for the [OpenableColumns#DISPLAY_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns#DISPLAY_NAME) key-column.